# Unable to import csv file into SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a db table's back up as 'csv file'.
I truncated the db table.
While importing the csv file using the `sql developer`, the data aren't getting inserted.
I amd following the procedure given in the tool.

Step by step procedure that I am following:

> Right-click on table name and click import csv.
>   Choose the csv back-up file
>   Choose the header column in the `data preview` screen and click next.
>   Move all available columns to selected columns' side in the `choose columns` screen and click next.
>   Source and the target data columns are matching fine in `column definition` screen. Click next.
>   click verify in the `finish` screen. Success on all columns.
>   In the last step, I am clicking on finish and then it is loading the tables but there is no data restored into the table.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I viewed many tutorials in order to restore the back-up using this method, but they are restoring the db without any issues. For me it is not happening

Comment: Is there any other work around? I mean, instead of going through this approach, can I try some other approach?

Answer (score 2):

When this sort of thing happens, the best way to triage is to have SQL Developer generate the INSERT statements instead of doing the actual insert.

So on one of the early steps, choose this -

[image]

Then when you finish the wizard, you should have an editor filled with INSERTs - one for every row in the CSV or Excel.

Connect to the right database, and execute those statements using F5.

And don't forget to COMMIT...if you want to keep the data.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was simply one of my column names in the csv did not match a column name in the table.
Compare each column in the table to the csv headings, and you should quickly see the issue.